# placement of l'dovid for nusach sefard

Tags: tefilla, shacharis-morning-prayer, elul, nusach-sefard

Nusach Ashkanaz places "l'dovid" always as the last teffilah. However, nusach sefard places it after aleinu during the week, but on shabbas it's placed after the yom: why is this?

Comment: my siddur is nusach ashkenaz and has it after the yom during the week. in fact, the directions say בכל יום אחר התפילה אומרים זה המזמור which would lead me to believe that l'dovid is an adjunct which must go after anything which is part of the tefilla on any day.

Comment: I was thinking of mincha and maariv,the point is that ashkanaz makes it the last thing of teffilah

Comment: @sam I would say Ashkenaz says it after tefillah, not the last thing of tefillah.

Comment: Customs vary in _nusach "S'farad"_: some say it after the _yom_ daily; some after "_Alenu_" (after "_An'im z'miros_" if said) even on _shabas_. But, yes, some do as you describe.

Comment: Maybe its meant to be after shachris, not after musaf.